# Facebook Page Plugin Issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook

I'm trying to integrate facebook on my website via the [Facebook Page Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/), but I have problems with the size of the created `iframe/span`. I'm using the following snippet to test the page plugin (i removed my AppID from the snippet):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Facebook Page Plugin Test</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Test">
    <meta name="author" content="Peter">
    <style>
        .fb-page, .fb-page:before, .fb-page:after
        {
            width: 500px;
            height: 400px;
            border: 1px solid #000;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/de_DE/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.1&appId=...';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

    <div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook" data-tabs="timeline" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true">
        <blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/facebook" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook">Facebook</a>
        </blockquote>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that the plugin won't show up when loading the page, because its internal `width` and `height` are set to `0`. When using the Chrome developer tools to change those values the page plugin will appear, but this is not a solution. I already tried to wrap the `div` in another one with defined `width` and `height`, but it didn't help. Also specifing a style for `.fb-page` as seen in the snippet doesn't work. All the solutions i tried so far will end up in the following result:

```
<span style="vertical-align: top; width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
    <iframe name="f37b63f71303c9" width="1000px" height="1000px" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen="true" scrolling="no" allow="encrypted-media" title="fb:page Facebook Social Plugin" src="https://www.facebook.com/v3.1/plugins/page.php?adapt_container_width=true&amp;app_id=127309047310662&amp;channel=https%3A%2F%2Fstaticxx.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2Fr%2Fmp2v3DK3INU.js%3Fversion%3D42%23cb%3Df2bfb9892342ec8%26domain%3D%26origin%3Dfile%253A%252F%252F%252Ff38080ee563c438%26relation%3Dparent.parent&amp;container_width=502&amp;hide_cover=false&amp;href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Ffacebook&amp;locale=de_DE&amp;sdk=joey&amp;show_facepile=true&amp;small_header=false&amp;tabs=timeline" style="border: none; visibility: visible; width: 0px; height: 0px;"></iframe>
</span>
```

You can clearly see that `width` and `height` of the `span` element are set to `0`. Does someone know what causes the problem and can come up with a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by adding the following css snippet:

```
.fb_iframe_widget span,
iframe.fb_iframe_widget_lift,
.fb_iframe_widget iframe {
    width: 500px !important;
    height: 500px !important;
}
```

Maybe someone will need this information in the future. I ended up not using the plugin, because facebook makes it so hard to integrate it and in my opinion it's not worth it.